# Calling ActionBarDrawerToggle's syncState in onCreate

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, actionbardrawertoggle

The Android documentation says

> Call syncState() from your Activity's onPostCreate to synchronize the indicator with the state of the linked DrawerLayout after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html

But the Navigation Drawer activity already implemented as a ready-made activity in Android Studio 3.0 calls that method in `onCreate`.

So which one is correct? Have there been changes recently?

Comment: The documentation is correct. Do it in `onPostCreate()`. Likely just a slip-up in the Android Studio template.

Comment: OK thank you. Can you tell me what problems it could cause in onCreate?

Comment: `DrawerLayout` saves and restores its drawer state during a configuration change - e.g., rotating the device - but the restore won't happen until after `onCreate()`, so if you sync in `onCreate()`, you could end up with the drawer open, but with the toggle icon in its closed state, the hamburger.

Comment: OK thank you very much!